How to convert a complex function into reactive function?
I have the following function
public ReturnVal doSOmething(String value){
     List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("val1", "val2", "val3");

     List<Root> roots = new ArrayList();
     List<Chain> chains= new ArrayList();

     Root rootValue = new Root(value);
     for(String id : ids){
        RootBuilder builder = new RootBuilder();
        builder.add(value, id);
        String newRoot = builder.build();
        roots.add(newRoot);

        ChainBuilder chainBUilder = new ChainBuilder();
        chains.add(builder.build(newRoot));
        rootValue = new Root(newRoot.value(), newRoot.level());
     } 

     Signature signature = signingService.sign(rootValue.value(), rootValue.level()); // Blocking, needs to connect to a server through TCP. Server needs a fix before webClient can be used.
     SigntureFactory factory = new SignatureFactory();

     for(int i = chains.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
       Root root = roots.get(i);
       signature = factory.createSignature(signature, chains.get(i), root.value())

    }
    return signature;
}

What it does is that it signs some data (its a custom signing system) and then afterwards adds a chain of custom ID-s to the signature.
What i cant figure out is can this be somehow made into a java reactive setup somehow? Builders and factory are a API classes, i cant modify them.
This method is called when a REST endpoint is invoked.
I could proably wrap signingService.sign into a Mono.just or Mono.fromSupplier But the loops seem like Flux but i need to return Mono in the end.

Which part do you actually want to make reactive? As long as your code does not include I/O or is not doing some heavy computation, I do not see any reason to not just wrap it into a simple Flux.just if you really want to return a Flux. To me it seems your question is more related to functional programming than WebFlux and reactive programming.

Also could you provide some code that compiles for us to try to understand what you are trying to achieve, there are a lot of typos, typing issues (newRoot is of type String but added to a List<Root>,...

@VincentC. there is alot of work to be done here. Other places are already on Flux/Mono, this was the last piece of the puzzle. All in all, request comes in thorugh REST endpoint. We do some preliinary work. We send data to siging service, whitch also has a whole lot of things it must do. We get signature back and add the stuff to signature, and then return the final signature. THe internals of the factories and builders and signer are not trivial and have some serious performance impacts. But they are a in house API-s so i cant share those.

Will edit the answer to switch paradigm and make the builder and signer return Mono using Mono.just. That should be enough there. Could you specify exactly which method (complete signature) you expect to be "slow" hence wrapped in a Publisher? This will help a lot.

Assumptions
Ok I am going to assume two things here:

by "complex" you mean having multiple data structures being modified in a single loop
you are more asking about how to convert an iterative function into a functional one

Why I assume those two things:

basically, reactive paradigm is very similar to functional paradigm and usually uses the same operators (Flux are very close to Stream in termes or capabilities)
a function being "complex" or not has nothing to do with the fact that it is hard or not to convert from an iterative paradigm to a functional one, but it is generally more complex to generate side effects (modify multiple data structures at once) with functional programming

Reduction operator
From what I understand, what you are mostly doing in your algorithm is taking a list of elements and projecting it to a single value by composing function successively (the famous f ∘ (f ∘ ... (f ∘ g))))
This is, in functional programming, called the reduction operator and seems to be what you mostly will be using in your algorithm.
Tuples
Now in functional programming, as in mathematics, a function does (should) not generate side effects, and will always return a single result.
Yet what we are sometimes doing in your iterative algorithm is that we are, at the same time, collecting some data into a List<Chain> and List<Root> and also computing the rootValue.
To do such things, we need a Vector which will hold our state during the composition of each function, so that state transits to each function successively. In functional programming we call these vector tuples.
Now, since JDK16, we can use record to "type" and "name" our tuples, which makes it more digest to read, but some would argue it is also more verbose.
Iterating over multiple collections
Now, similarly to iterative paradigm, it is not really possible without binding two collections to iterate over both at the same time. IntStream comes to rescue here (but, as in iterative paradigm, there is hundreds of way of doing the same thing): we can stream an arbitrary number of int and then use those to iterate over our two collections at the same time.
Proposal
Saying this, this is what I find the most fitting for your case:
  public Mono<String> doSomething(String value) {

    var ids = Arrays.asList("val1", "val2", "val3");

    var rootWithChainsAndRoots = ids.stream()
                                    .reduce(Mono.just(new RootWithChainsAndRoots(new Root(value, "a level"), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>())),
                                            (reduction, s) -> reduction.flatMap(actualReduction -> {
                                              RootBuilder builder = new RootBuilder();
                                              builder.add(value, s);
                                              Mono<Root> newRoot = builder.build();

                                              return newRoot.flatMap(actualNewRoot -> {
                                                actualReduction.roots().add(actualNewRoot);

                                                ChainBuilder chainBuilder = new ChainBuilder();
                                                Mono<Chain>  newChain     = chainBuilder.build(actualNewRoot);

                                                return newChain.map(actualNewChain -> {
                                                  actualReduction.chains().add(actualNewChain);
                                                  return actualReduction.withRoot(actualNewRoot);
                                                });
                                              });
                                            }),
                                            (_, s) -> s);

    return rootWithChainsAndRoots.flatMap(actualRootWithChainsAndRoots -> {

      var signature = signingServiceSign(actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.root()
                                                                     .value(),
                                         actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.root()
                                                                     .level()); // Blocking, needs to connect to a server through TCP. Server needs a fix before webClient can be used.
      var factory = new SignatureFactory();

      var composedSignature = IntStream.range(0, actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.chains().size())
                                       .mapToObj(index -> new ChainAndRoot(actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.chains().get(actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.chains().size() - 1 - index),
                                                                           actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.roots().get(actualRootWithChainsAndRoots.chains().size() - 1 - index)))
                                       .reduce(signature,
                                               (previous, chainAndRoot) -> factory.createSignature(previous,
                                                                                                   chainAndRoot.chain(),
                                                                                                   chainAndRoot.root().value()),
                                               (_, next) -> next);

      return composedSignature.map(Signature::content);
    });
  }

  private record RootWithChainsAndRoots(Root root, List<Chain> chains, List<Root> roots) {

    public RootWithChainsAndRoots withRoot(final Root newRoot) {
      return new RootWithChainsAndRoots(newRoot, this.chains(), this.roots());
    }
  }

  private record ChainAndRoot(Chain chain, Root root) {

  }

  private Mono<Signature> signingServiceSign(final String value, final String level) {
    return Mono.just(new Signature("signature: %s\nlevel: %s".formatted(value, level)));
  }

  private static class RootBuilder {

    private final List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

    void add(final String value, final String id) {
      content.add("value: %s\nid: %s".formatted(value, id));
    }

    Mono<Root> build() {
      return Mono.just(new Root(content.toString(), "a level"));
    }
  }

  private static class ChainBuilder {

    Mono<Chain> build(Root newRoot) {
      return Mono.just(new Chain(newRoot));
    }
  }

  private static class SignatureFactory {

    Mono<Signature> createSignature(Mono<Signature> signature, final Chain chain, final String value) {
      return signature.map(actual -> new Signature("signature: %s\nchain: %s\nvalue: %s".formatted(actual, chain, value)));
    }
  }

  private record Root(String value, String level) {

  }

  private record Chain(Root newRoot) {

  }

  private record Signature(String content) {

  }

Note
This does not change much whether methods returns a Publisher or their non-reactive counterparts, when you are already using functional paradigm, usually you are already just a few .map, .flatMap or .concatMap away from the already implemented solution.

I will get back to this once im back at work
